# multiple function declare in head file

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I have a function `sortList()` which uses `mergeList()`. And I declare them in the header file "sortList.h", and implement them respectively in sortList.cpp and mergeList.cpp. However when I compile, there is an error saying I didn't declare function `mergeList()` in the file "sortList.cpp". I wonder since I already declare `mergeList()` in the header file, shouldn't it be complied before implementation of `sortList()` (which uses `mergeList`)? Or shall I declare `mergeList()` again in `sortList.cpp`? Thanks!

sortList.h:

```
#ifndef SORTLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define SORTLIST_H_INCLUDED

struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
  };

ListNode *mergeList(ListNode *left, ListNode *right);
ListNode *sortList(ListNode *head);

#endif // SORTLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Both C files #include the header, right?

Comment: Yes in the main.cpp, I have #include "sortList.h"

Comment: Just in main.cpp is not enough. sortList.cpp needs to #include "sortList.h", otherwise it won't know that `mergeList` exists.

Comment: You should probably have a separate `.h` file for each `.cpp` file, declaring the functions that are defined in it. If there are structures used in all of them, that declaration should be in a third `.h` file that they both use.

Comment: Thank you! This works! So from this issue I learnt that if one function a() wants to use another function b(), it has to declare b() in the implementation file (a.cpp). Is this correct?

Comment: @user3614235 `if one function a() wants to use another function b(), it has to declare b() in the implementation file (a.cpp). Is this correct?` I would say if your module a() is defined in a.cpp and wants to call b(), then you should `#include "a.h"` from a.cpp. For example, if b is `cos` then you must `#include <cmath>` because that is where `cos` is declared. All modules that use `cos` should eventually `#include <cmath>`. If many modules use the same headers, one strategy is to place all include directives into a file like `config.h` and then include that one file in every module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q:I wonder since I already declare mergeList() in the header file, shouldn't it be complied before implementation of sortList() (which uses mergeList)?`

In C, when header file is included (ie:`#include "sortList.h"`), it is as though the `#include ...` line is replaced with the entire code of the specified `.h` file is inserted at that point.  In essence, the content of the `.h` file becomes part of the `.c` file (or, `.cpp` file) being compiled.

This is true for each `.c` file (or, `.cpp` file) which includes any specific `.h` file.

Hence, in the above question, `"...shouldn't it be complied before implementation of sortList()"`, the answer is 'no'.  Not 'before', but rather 'with'.  Specifically, if prototypes `sortList()` and `mergeList()` exist in `sortlist.h`, for it is customary for both sortList.cpp and mergeList.cpp to `#include "sortList.h"`".  Thus, the code of `sortList.h` becomes part of both these files.

`Q:Or shall I declare mergeList() again in sortList.cpp?`

No, just make sure that `sortList.h` is included in `sortList.cpp.`

Comment: thanks! This makes sense  to me. So header file is like structure of different functions, in the header file it would include other functions' header file  and data structure's header file if they will be used. Whereas in each .cpp file, it only needs to include the corresponding header file.

Comment: @user3614235, It seems you understand the concept properly.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `sortList` function to use the `mergeList` function which is defined in a different source file, it will need to know that the function actually exists, and what it looks like. Adding

```
#include "sortList.h"
```

to "sortList.cpp" would be the easiest and most sensible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that all cpp files are compiled to object files which than are linked.
So treat every cpp file as its own module and supply the compiler with all information for that compile-target.

see: http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html

As already commented the easiest way to do this is to `#include "sortlist.h"` or to put function-prototypes on top of every cpp-file that uses the functions.